# Unexpected result of case expression

Tags: mysql

The following case expression results in `a`,

```
select case 0 when true  then 'c' when 'true1222' then 'a' else 'b' end;
```

Anyone knows why? How could `0` be equal to `true1222`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem is - use 0 as CASE, 0 == false
so query compare:

- TRUE - not, go forward
- 'true1222' - FALSE == 0, OK

try to change query:

```
SELECT
    CASE 3
WHEN TRUE THEN
    'c'
WHEN 'true1222' THEN
    'a'
ELSE
    'b'
END;
```

and it return expected - 'b'

Comment: Perhaps also, `'true1222'` was converted to numeric for comparison with `0`.  A string without leading digits converts to `0`.